# How can we convert an Ethereum address (string) to Solidity's address type in Javascript in order to pass it to a contract function as an argument?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have a function in a Solidity smart contract like this:

```
function mint (address _recipient, string _name) public onlyOwner {

 uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
_safemint(_recipient, newItemId);

// etc

}
```

I try to pass from the front-end

```
 import { ethers } from "ethers";
  let tmpdata = ethers.utils.getAddress("0x6f...etc"); //
    
    let nftTxn = await connectedContract.mintNFT(tmpdata, "some string");
    await nftTxn.wait();
```

I copy paste the addresses to make sure they are correct, but this throws an error everytime. And I think it doesn't work because we'd need an address type as first argument right? I can't find out how to achieve that, anyone can help and point me in the right direction here?

console gives me

data: "0x08c379a00000000000000......etc"
message: "execution reverted: ERC721: mint to to zero address

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about type conversion since solidity manages a string as an address when you pass it through parameters. It seems that tmpdata is returning a Null or maybe an undefined value. Could you please try the same code adding an await before 'ethers.utils.getAddress(...);' ?